# recvfrom() get the wrong source address

Tags: recv

when i recvfrom(), the received message is correct, but the source address is totally a mess,
why is that happening?

```
char traid_messageR[MAXDATASIZE];
socklen_t addlen;
struct sockaddr_in source_addr;
if((numbytes=recvfrom(udp_sockfd, traid_messageR, 256, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&source_addr, &addlen)) == -1)
{
    perror("recvfrom");
    exit(1);
}
```

the result is like this:

```
(gdb) print source_addr
$1 = {sin_family = 61428, sin_port = 42, sin_addr = {s_addr = 49809}, 
  sin_zero = "\234\352\377\277\310\352\377\277"}
```

the 49809 looks like a port number, but it is the port number of this receiver...does any one have idea why is this?thanks a lot
oh, another thing, i used this in a select() loop, IF_ISSET(und_socked,%fds),then exceute the above code, does this affect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you didn't assign value to addlen

```
addlen = sizeof(source_addr)
```

UPDATE: refer to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/recvfrom.html
The manual says

> address_len Specifies  the length of the sockaddr structure pointed
>   to
>       by the address argument.  .....
>        If the address argument is not a null pointer and the protocol provides  the source address of messages, the source address of the
>   received message is stored in the sockaddr structure pointed to by the
>   address argument, and the length of this address is stored in the
>   object pointed to by the address_len argument.

Comment: yeah, after assigning value to addlen, it works, by i don't quiet understand, aren't addlen suppose to be changed during recvfrom? why i need to assign value to it at the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I found it explained better here:

> In this case, addrlen is a value-
>   result argument.  Before the call, it should be initialized to the
>   size of the buffer associated with src_addr.  Upon return, addrlen is
>   updated to contain the actual size of the source address.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html